# Troubleshooting a Failing Transaction in Ethereum Account Abstraction

Tags: ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets, account-abstraction, erc-4337, gasless

I'm attempting to use account abstraction for transactions on the Mumbai chain without a paymaster, where my smart contract wallet pays the fees. Despite following the process and checking against the Pimlico package on GitHub, my transactions are failing, and I'm unsure why.

```
smart contrct wallet : 0x3E2341F136005F88323dDdF5BA025c0b9Bb41feF
EntryPoint contract : 0x5FF137D4b0FDCD49DcA30c7CF57E578a026d2789
```

I have deployed my smart contract wallet properly, [txHash](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x40da8f22f4ea27dd116ec54ab7b23f8858c67cee8d73a244b68ffd3bc2988bf4)

My Js code:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { JsonRpcProvider } = require("@ethersproject/providers");

const { EntryPointAddress, WalletAddress, SCAddress } = require("./data.js");
const TokenABI = require("./token.json");

function convertBigIntToString(obj) {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "bigint") {
      obj[key] = obj[key].toString();
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key] !== null) {
      convertBigIntToString(obj[key]);
    }
  }
}

class CustomJsonRpcProvider extends JsonRpcProvider {
  async sendUserOperation(userOperation, entryPoint) {
    const method = "eth_sendUserOperation";
    // Convert BigInt to string
    convertBigIntToString(userOperation);
    const params = [userOperation, entryPoint];
    return this.send(method, params);
  }
}

const NONCE = 21;

async function main() {

const rpcUrl =
  "https://api.stackup.sh/v1/node/8d4f475df648de...4d52829a8131fba";

  const customProvider = new CustomJsonRpcProvider(rpcUrl);
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  const EntryPoint = await ethers.getContractAt(
    "EntryPoint",
    EntryPointAddress
  );

  const opObject = await getUserOperation();
  console.log("opObject : ", opObject);

  const res = await EntryPoint.connect(deployer).getUserOpHash(opObject);
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "6a694a78c...565da252dc8"
    ); 
    const signature = await wallet.signMessage(ethers.toBeArray(res));
    opObject.signature = signature;

  try {
    const userOpHash = await customProvider.sendUserOperation(
      opObject,
      EntryPointAddress
    );
    console.log("User Operation Hash:", userOpHash);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending user operation:", error);
  }

  // await EntryPoint.connect(deployer).handleOps([opObject],SCAddress);
}

const getUserOperation = async () => {
  const [signer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  const tokenIN = "0x8De6DcD5Bd1DeC1e8197FB4E0057498e7207133b";
  const SwapAddress = "0x31A92fCA50F511db28b57185ED6Ae12f565F2762";
  const TokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenIN, TokenABI, signer);
  const SwapAllowance = ethers.parseEther("100");

  const userOperation = {
    sender: "0x3E2341F136005F88323dDdF5BA025c0b9Bb41feF",
    nonce: NONCE,
    initCode: ethers.hexlify(ethers.toUtf8Bytes("")),
    callData: TokenContract.interface.encodeFunctionData("approve", [
      SwapAddress,
      SwapAllowance,
    ]),
    callGasLimit: 112489,
    verificationGasLimit: 87538,
    preVerificationGas: 93636,
    maxFeePerGas: 100_000_000_000,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: 100_000_000_000,
    paymasterAndData: ethers.hexlify(ethers.toUtf8Bytes("")),
  };

  const hash = await getUserOpHash(userOperation, EntryPointAddress, 80001);

  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "6a694a7...da252dc8"
  );

  const signature = await wallet.signMessage(ethers.toBeArray(hash));
  userOperation.signature = signature;
  return userOperation;
}



const getUserOpHash = async (op, entryPoint, chainId) => {

  const abiCoder = new ethers.AbiCoder();
  const userOpHash = ethers.keccak256(
    abiCoder.encode(
      [
        "address",
        "uint256",
        "bytes",
        "bytes",
        "uint256",
        "uint256",
        "uint256",
        "uint256",
        "uint256",
        "bytes",
      ],
      [
        op.sender,
        op.nonce,
        op.initCode,
        op.callData,
        op.callGasLimit,
        op.verificationGasLimit,
        op.preVerificationGas,
        op.maxFeePerGas,
        op.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
        op.paymasterAndData,
      ]
    )
  );
  const enc = abiCoder.encode(
    ["bytes32", "address", "uint256"],
    [userOpHash, entryPoint, BigInt(chainId)]
  );

  return ethers.keccak256(enc);

};

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

I'm getting an userOpHash at the end of tx but the transaction is still reverting,Here is my latest failed tx: [txHash](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x29877a8844b4a6bfe6967a113993521fbbb3babae94440cec4d6ab321779b0b2)

I have gone through Pimlico package on Github to make sure the signature is correct. can't understand why it's still failing.

I have already tried calling handleOps rather than calling eth_sendUserOperation directly, still got the same error, here is the tx: [txHash](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x92a8d450f9260b85ed8957482dd22f33a4f3f5b6f64eb0ec43d6fe5e66d4f21a)

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights into resolving this issue

Answer (score 0):

The callData seems to be incorrect. I simulated your transaction on Tenderly and the call from the Entry Point to the Smart Account is reverting.
I see you are passing in the call data of an approval. Can you double check if that is correct because simulating just the callData is also failing on Tenderly

Comment: Hi Yashasvi , thanks for responding. I directly called the  approve function using the EOA used to create the smart contract wallet and the tx was successful , 

[txHash] (https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x48f99169a8bd54c3a23285e910e72109c3f1df1b4346da5c5894a36f2cf77097)

you can see in the above code how i'm sending my callData, i have gone through multiple libraries of AA providing services and all are sending their data in this format. 
please let me know if their is another way to convert my call to bytes.

thanks